# d2: Immutable structs with opApply do not compile when initialized with non-default constructor

Tags: foreach, immutability, d

Consider following code:

```
immutable struct Test {
    this(int foo) { }

    int opApply(int delegate(ref int) dg) {
        return (0);
    }
}

int main(string[] argv) {
    auto set = Test(); // compiles
    // auto set = Test(1); // Error: cannot uniquely infer foreach argument types

    foreach (item; set) { }

    return 0;
}
```

When `Test` structure is built using default no-argument constructor, code compiles fine, but when I try to use any other constuctor, I get compile time error. If I comment out `foreach`, code will compile. If I comment out `immutable`, code will compile too.

What is the reason for this kind of behavior and how it should be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, at least using DMD version 2.059, it doesn't compile (tested on Windows 7 and FreeBSD) with either constructor.

The reason for this ought to be fairly obvious. By making a struct (or class) immutable, you are simply applying immutable to every member of that struct (or class). However, the constructors do not become immutable. That is, when when you declare `immutable struct Test` you have effectively done the following:

```
struct Test {
    this(int foo) { }
    immutable int opApply(int delegate(ref int) dg) {
        return (0);
    }
}
```

Commenting out the foreach loop allows the code to compile because foreach is looking for an opApply method without the `immutable` declaration.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you could simply make the struct `final` instead of `immutable`, or, if you want to keep most of your struct immutable...

```
struct Test {
    // Anything that needs to be mutable should go up here
    int opApply(int delegate(ref uint) dg) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Anything put in this block is immutable
    immutable {
        this(int foo) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, except of that `immutable struct` implies `immutable this(int foo) { }`. It seems that constructor in immutable struct is still mutable, so specifying `this(int foo) immutable {}` explicitly is enough to resolve this conflict, and code just works then. However, thank you for helping me figure this out.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I completely missed that. You were correct in filing the bug report. I'll edit my answer to accommodate for that.